# Change cell values in excel files and copy the changes to a new column using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to reduce a cell value in a column, such as "250-1824-02" to "250-1824" and update the new value to a new column in the same excel sheet using c#. Please Help

I have generated the coding upto the below level:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = false;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(textBox1.Text, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);



Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);

        string value = string.Empty;
        for (int Loop = 1; Loop <= range.Row; Loop++)
        {
            value = Convert.ToString(xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + Loop, "A" + Loop].get_Value(misValue));
            xlWorkSheet.Range["B" + Loop, "B" + Loop].set_Value(misValue, value.Remove(8, 3));
        }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply ...could you please explain me on "Loop" that have been used here

Comment: i modified it as give below: It throws an error message called "type mismatch". xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                int x = 0;
                for (x = 0; x <= xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count; x++)
                xlWorkSheet.Cells["I", x] = Convert.ToString(xlWorkSheet.Cells["C", x]).Remove(8, 3);

Comment: it throws an error called "Error 1 Property, indexer, or event 'Value' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.get_Value(object)' or 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Value(object, object)'

Comment: @hansikaattanayake, Code is changed......

    string value = string.Empty;
    for (int Loop = 1; Loop <= range.Row; Loop++)
    {
      value = Convert.ToString(xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + Loop, "A" + Loop].get_Value(misValue));
      xlWorkSheet.Range["B" + Loop, "B" + Loop].set_Value(misValue, value.Remove(8, 3));
     }